# Insert, Update, Delete are not applied on SQL Server CE database file for Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I am developing a Windows Mobile 6.5 application with C# using Visual Studio 2008, it's connected to a SQL Server CE database.

I used this code to insert rows, the value of each column is related to a textBox string :

```
namespace GesTPL
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        public Form4()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Form RefToForm1 { get; set; }

        static String pathDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        static String pathDB = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathDir, "releve.sdf");
        static String connectionString = string.Format(@"DataSource={0}", pathDB);
        SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);

        private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        private void button_Fermer_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.RefToForm1.Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button_OK_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "" || textBox5.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fill in all the information first!");
            }
            else
            {
                SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO compteur(numeroCompteur, idGeographique, abonne, police) VALUES(@numeroCompteur, @idGeographique, @abonne, @police)", connection);
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numeroCompteur", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idGeographique", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@abonne", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@police", textBox5.Text);

                try
                {
                    int affectedrows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (affectedrows > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Data added successfully!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Failed to add data!");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the modifications are only applied on the database in the emulator, but not on the database `.sdf` file I have in my project.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is expected and normal. By executing a WM project from VS, the binaries and content files (.sdf in this case) are COPIED to the device/emulator. If you want to keep a copy of the modified .sdf file you'll have to manually extract it from the emulator yourself.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically extract the database file from the device and replace the original one in the project ?

Comment: You may use itsutils (remote tools: http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/XdaUtils) to download files from an ActiveSync connected device: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/02/26/pc-activesync-can-be-used-to-automate-tasks-on-device-connection/

Answer (score 0):

Select the `releve.sdf` database file in your project, go to the **Properties** section, and make sure `Build Action = Content` and `Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer`.

[image: screenshot]

That **should** be all you need, but if there are other issues you may want to double check the file location:

```
    private void button_OK_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(pathDB, "Check Path Location!");
        // ... rest of your code
    }
```

Comment: He wants to go the other way, I think.  He wants changes to the device DB to come back to the PC.

Comment: When I first added the database file to my project, I choosed not to copy the original file to the project directory when I was asked, so the file with the yellow icon doesn't appear. I don't know if this is right, but at least I can see the modifications I apply inside the emulator.

Comment: Then your program is working correctly. If you want to see your database entries on your PC, you will need to copy that database from your emulator back to the PC.